# double quotation marks, because journal title begins with quotation - biblatex-sbl

Tags: biblatex, quotation

My problem: When an article begins with a quotation, it is shown in the notes and the bibliography with two quotation marks, e.g.:

> Leyerle, Blake. “”In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth” (Gen1,1): John Chrysostom on the Gaze.”JECS1 (1993): 159–174.

I am wondering, how to avoid this and transform it to:

> Leyerle, Blake. “'In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth' (Gen1,1): John Chrysostom on the Gaze.”JECS1 (1993): 159–174.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{leyerle:1993,
author = {Leyerle, Blake},
title = {"In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth” (Gen 1,1): John Chrysostom on the Gaze},
shorttitle = {Chrysostom},
journaltitle = {Journal of Early Christian Studies},
shortjournal = {JECS},
volume = {1},
date = {1993},
pages = {159-174}
}


@incollection{Ab.2005,
 author = {Ab, Tom},
 date = {2005},
 title = {Gǝ’ǝz Anaphora},
 shorttitle = {Gǝ’ǝz Anaphora},
 editor = {Zenk, Raul},
 pages = {132--144},
 location = {Rom},
 booktitle = {Studi},
series = {Orientalia Christiana Analecta},
 shortseries = {OCA},
}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl,ibidtracker=false,idemtracker=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mknormrange{#1}} \DeclareFieldFormat{pagepages}{\mknormrange[\mkpageprefix]{#1}} \DeclareFieldFormat{pagesin}{\mknormrange[\mkpageprefix]{#1} \usebibmacro{in}} \DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

genannt\footnote{Vgl.: \cite{leyerle:1993}.} oder\footcite{Ab.2005}.
\printbiblist{abbreviations}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, if the answers you are receiving solve your problems, you should go back over your questions and mark them as answered (with green tick on the answer) (and if you wish upvote them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `csquote`'s `\enquote` or `biblatex`'s `\mkbibquote` instead of the hard-coded quotation marks `"` and `”`.

For most intents and purposes it does not matter if you choose `\enquote` or `\mkbibquote`, since `\mkbibquote` will use `\enquote` internally if `csquotes` is loaded. But there are a few things to keep in mind

- `\mkbibquote` is only defined by `biblatex`, so your entries will only work with `biblatex`.
- `\enquote` is a `csquotes` command. That means it is independent of `biblatex` and the entries will work even if they are processed with classical BibTeX as long as `csquotes` is loaded.

In practice the difference is not going to matter much, since it is recommended to load `csquotes` with `biblatex`.

`biblatex-examples.bib` uses `\mkbibquote`, so this is what I use in the MWE

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl,ibidtracker=false,idemtracker=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{leyerle:1993,
  author       = {Leyerle, Blake},
  title        = {\mkbibquote{In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth}
                  (Gen 1,1): John Chrysostom on the Gaze},
  shorttitle   = {Chrysostom},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Early Christian Studies},
  shortjournal = {JECS},
  volume       = {1},
  date         = {1993},
  pages        = {159-174}
}
@incollection{Ab.2005,
  author      = {Ab, Tom},
  date        = {2005},
  title       = {Gǝ’ǝz Anaphora},
  editor      = {Zenk, Raul},
  pages       = {132--144},
  location    = {Rom},
  booktitle   = {Studi},
  series      = {Orientalia Christiana Analecta},
  shortseries = {OCA},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

genannt\autocite[Vgl.:][]{leyerle:1993} oder\footcite{Ab.2005}.
\printbiblist{abbreviations}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Leyerle, Blake. “‘In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth’ (Gen 1,1): John Chrysostom on the Gaze”. JECS 1 (1993): 159–74.]

Comment: Congratulations for your 100K!

Comment: @egreg Thank you!